# Physicist notation for spatial orbital

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In quantum chemistry, the two-electron integrals often denoted as physicist's and chemist's notations.

For spin orbital, the physicist's and chemist's notations are
$$ \langle pq | rs \rangle = \int \int p(1)^* q(2)^* \frac{1}{r_{12}}  r(1) s(2) d^4 x_1 d^4 x_2 $$

$$ [ pq | rs ] = \int \int p(1)^* q(1) \frac{1}{r_{12}}  r(2)^* s(2) d^4 x_1 d^4 x_2 $$

respectively.

For spatial orbital, I have only found the chemist notation
$$ ( pq | rs ) = \int \int p(1)^* q(1) \frac{1}{r_{12}}  r(2)^* s(2) d^3 r_1 d^3 r_2 $$

Is there any physicist's notation for spatial orbital?

Comment: As far as Szabo/Ostlund is concerned, there's no other notation (Table 2.2, p 68).

Comment: yep, that's the reason for asking this question..

Comment: I guessed that that might be the case :) but that's all the info I have anyway, thought it was worth a mention anyway since you didn't mention the book.

Comment: Yes, there exist "physicist's notation" for integrals over spatial orbitals and symbolically it is looks the same as "physicist's notation" for integrals over spin orbital: the good-ol' Dirac bra-kets is what is usually called "physicist's notation".